# Can I change the initial none value displayed for a ModelChoiceField so it's not "---------"?

Tags: django, django-forms

I've built an inline form, where the field labels don't show up, so the form relies on placeholders to tell the user what the field is:

[image]

The second field in is a ModelChoiceField. Is there any way to change the default "none" value to use the field name instead of the "---------" dashes?

Comment: Please also include the code that generates the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forms.py`

```
class ModelNameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ModelName.objects.all(),empty_label="*** SomeThing **", label="Department")
```